# when I run my tests i get this err No specs found

Tags: typescript, testing, jasmine, specifications

I tried to run npm run test   i get this error
Randomized with seed 88747
Started

No specs found
Finished in 0.021 seconds
Incomplete: No specs found
Randomized with seed 88747 (jasmine --random=true --seed=88747)

jasmine.json file and project structure and issue [image]

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for js file but It seem that your unit test file is a .ts extension